# Refactoring NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

This code now sits in a `UIViewController`:

```
lazy var categoryFRC: NSFetchedResultsController<Category> = {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Category> = Category.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "text", ascending: true)]
    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate) as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self
    do {
        try frc.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
    }
    return frc
}()
```

And this is the way I refer to the fetched categories with a for-loop:

```
let category = (self.categoryFRC.fetchedObjects?[index])! as Category
```

I would like to access the same `CoreData` entity from a different `ViewController`.

1. May I know what is the right way to restructure my code?
2. Do I create a new class?
3. And how do I handle the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`?
4. Must all the `ViewControllers` referring to the `fetchedResults` be a
   subclass of `NSFetchResultsControllerDelegate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done is pull all non-view rendering/user event handling from ViewControllers and put that logic into another class.  In your case you want to create a new class and put the categoryFRC logic into the new class

```
class DataController {
  lazy var categoryFRC: NSFetchedResultsController<Category> = {
  let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Category> = Category.fetchRequest()
  fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "text", ascending: true)]
  let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate) as! AppDelegate
  let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
  let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
  frc.delegate = self

  do {
    try frc.performFetch()
  } catch {
    fatalError("Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
  }

  return frc
  }()
}
```

Then in the ViewController store an instance of DataController:

```
class ViewController {
  var dataController : DataController!

  func viewDidLoad() {
    dataController = DataController()
    dataController.categoryFRC.delegate = <Class that adopts NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
  }
}
```

Other observations:

- Create another class that adopts NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate.  Then set the categoryFRC.delegate to the new class.  This way the new class is responsible for the FRC delegate methods, not the view controller.
- pull the do/try/catch around the frc.performFetch() from the lazy categoryFRC definition.  Are you sure that you want to perform a fetch each time you access categoryFRC?  I'd put the do/try/catch logic into a new function.
- Look at your for loop, what happens if fetchedObjects? is nil?  Wouldn't you crash because you are then unwrapping a nil value?

Comment: Right now my view controller adopts the NSFetchedControllerDelegate and the delegate's functions are referring to a tableView declared in my ViewController. So what I should do is to create a new class for the delegate and then create a tableview variable within the delegate and then right after i set the delegate for the FRC, set the variable within the delegate to point to the tableview?

Comment: Would you recommend that I create a sharedInstance so that I do not create a new DataController instance when I need to refer to it in ViewController2?